# Add one part of git repo as submodule to another

Tags: git, git-submodules, mount

I need o duplicate one folder in my project o another. But when I try:

`git submodule add ./first-folder ./second-folder/sumbodule`

it fails with:

```
fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:username/projectname.git/first-folder' into submodule path
```

Am I doing something wrong or it's impossible by default and I should just mount it somehow? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can only add entire repositories as submodules. See [git submodule documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). There is a parameter `path` but that applies to the path where the submodule appears in the 'superproject', not to a path inside the submodule.

To achieve what you want, you need to make the `first-folder` a separate git repository and include that as submodule to all of your projects.

Answer (score 0):

From ./second-folder/sumbodule, try to execute below command:

```
cd ./second-folder
git submodule add <git@github ...> sumbodule
```